# Normalise a string into rows\columns with sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Does anyone know the best way I can normalized a string in the below format:-

```
'(20111026,1000,34.10)(20111027,1000,44.10)(20111028,1000,54.10)(20111029,1000,64.10)(20111030,1000,74.10)'
```

Into 5 rows with 3 columns?

```
|Date       |Time     |Amount|
-------------------------------
|2011-10-26 |10:00:00 |34.10 |
|2011-10-27 |10:00:00 |44.10 |
|2011-10-28 |10:00:00 |54.10 |
|2011-10-29 |10:00:00 |64.10 |
|2011-10-30 |10:00:00 |74.10 |
```

I have managed to do this using a string parser with delimiter of ')(' to get the rows and ',' again to get the columns. However when I do this against 7 million strings the db blow out.

This is the SQL I have got so far:

```
DECLARE @Text VARCHAR(500) = '(20111026,1000,34.10)(20111027,1000,44.10)(20111028,1000,54.10)(20111029,1000,64.10)(20111030,1000,74.10)'

SELECT  
   TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [1]) AS StartDate ,
   CAST(TRY_CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(HOUR, ( [2] / 100 ) % 100, DATEADD(MINUTE, ( [2] / 1 ) % 100, CAST('00:00' AS TIME)))) AS VARCHAR(8)) AS StartTime ,
   TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(16, 6), [3]) AS Amount
FROM    
   (SELECT 
       X.Ordinal AS RoNum ,
       Y.Ordinal AS ColNum ,
       REPLACE(Y.StringValue, '(', '') AS Value
    FROM 
       dbo.ParseString(@Text, ')(') X
    CROSS APPLY 
       dbo.ParseString(StringValue,',') Y
    WHERE 
       NOT Y.StringValue = '') AS SRC 
PIVOT
( MIN(Value) FOR ColNum IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) AS PVT;
```

Parse string function:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseString]
   (@String VARCHAR(500), @Delimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN
     (WITH Results AS
        (SELECT 1 AS Ordinal,
            LTRIM(LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String + @Delimiter)-1)) AS StringValue,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), RIGHT(@String + @Delimiter, LEN(@String) - CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String+@Delimiter) + 1)) AS Remaining
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  Ordinal+1,
            LTRIM(LEFT(Remaining, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, Remaining)-1)),
            RIGHT(Remaining, LEN(Remaining) - CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, Remaining))
    FROM    Results
    WHERE   LEN(Remaining) > 0)
 SELECT Ordinal,
        StringValue
 FROM   Results
)
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would do that outside of the database, for example with .NET. Do you know that you can even use .NET in sql-server? That would be the most efficient approach: [SQL Server CLR Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: you are dealing with mysql or sql-server? you have tagged both in your post but the syntax look as sql-server

Comment: I'm in sql server 2012, and I'm using ssis firstly calling an sp to persist the strings unnormalised from a flat file. Then moving through the data flow to transform the unnormalised data to normalised data using sps, hense the reason to normalise this string. I tagged mysql just in case there is anyone from that community with any suggestions. Thanks for the reply, yep i thought so, just wanted to normalise the data on the way in, rather than the api. I do not really want to use CLRs in this instance, as I want the process to be really slimline.

Comment: @Andrew'go-sql'Fenna: I'm not sure what _slimline_ means in this context. This article also suggests CLR
 and links to another article which shows the most efficient implementation: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @Andrew'go-sql'Fenna: i've tested that function with a table that contains 20 million rows and selected one million strings(separated by comma) from it. It lasts 80 seconds.

Comment: By slimline I mean I'd want the process to run really quickly and efficiently. I don't want to use anything that will add complexity to the process, i'd rather keep things in sql than writing c# in a CLR for maintainability. For a little context, I need to normalise 11GB of unnormalised text files in less than 10mins from staging to production i'm looking at 77million rows. And this string is a column in the text files and it the last piece of the puzzle, if i can normalize this, then I've cracked it, if I can't then the api will have to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to resort to splitting string for something like this. The format you posted is almost correct to use table value constructors. Using replace to stick commas in between the set of values already wrapped nicely in () means you can do this pretty easily using some dynamic sql.

```
declare @String varchar(max) = '(20111026,1000,34.10)(20111027,1000,44.10)(20111028,1000,54.10)(20111029,1000,64.10)(20111030,1000,74.10)'
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = 'select * from (VALUES ' + REPLACE(@String, ')(', '),(') + ')N (col1, col2, col3)'

select @SQL
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: The problem is that that @String is actually a column from another table so the dynamic sql will not work...eg  SELECT * FROM StagingTable LZ CROSS APPLY(VALUES LZ.String) N (COL1, COL2, COL3) ANY IDEAS?

Comment: I could probably apply the replace to the column before i get the data out. UPDATE StagingTable SET String =  REPLACE(String, ')(', '),(') if that helps? but how do i use the values function not he data has been updated?